# WCF returns non valid XML?

Tags: c#, wcf

I got a WCF service with a datacontract that contains a simple string property. This string property can sometimes contain illegal characters(according to XML standard), like "`&#x1e;`" (instead of "  "). Is there a way to get WCF to always put out valid XML?

Regards

Comment: Where are these illegal characters coming from? Are you saying that your assign the string property "What's this?" and it is then transmitted by WCF as "What's&#x1e;this"?

Comment: Yes, that´s correct, it is probably dubbel so it might be a separator double and this match the "&#x1e;".

Comment: Can you please give an example?

Comment: You can check to see if there's a coding problem.